# I can't connect to the router because password field only allows 15 characters and my password is longer

Tags: router

As in the title. I can't type my password into password field, because it only allows 15 characters there. And my password is obviously longer than that. It used to work in the past.

Comment: Did you recently update your router?

Comment: With the information you have given, the only advice that can be offered is to do a factory reset and choose a shorter password when you reconfigure it.

Comment: Could it be you used to type or paste the long password and not notice the input stopped after 15 characters every time? And these 15 characters were (and still are) the real password because it had been truncated in the same manner while being set up? But you only recently noticed the discrepancy and got confused? In other words: try the first 15 characters anyway.

Comment: Is it possible it asks for a WPS Pin instead? If so, there should be a link under the password field where you can supply a WPA2 password instead.

Comment: @LPchip WPS is broken, we should encourage anyone using WiFi to disable it. Check out WPS-pixie attack on Google.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, yes I know WPS is broken, but he may still see that. I wasn't posting this as a solution, but as a way to verify what is going on.

Comment: Are we talking about the administrator password to log into the router? Or your WPA2-PSK? If we are talking about the WPA password, factory reset & update the firmware. If the full password worked in the past, absent of configuration/firmware changes it should still work. Reset, upgrade the firmware and test it.